# Replacing Apache Dir with File?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

So, I have an apache server, and a `api` directory. When you go to `/api` it shows the directory's contents, which looks somewhat like this

```
Index of /api

[ICO]   Name    Last modified   Size    Description
[PARENTDIR] Parent Directory        -    
[   ]   admins  2016-08-10 22:29    15   
[   ]   users   2016-08-10 22:17    30   
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at quea-bjskistad.c9users.io Port 443
```

Instead of showing this, I want it to show a file that goes by the path of `.*quea/api.html`. What do I need to do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an alias, check https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html

Something like:

```
Alias /api /path/to/api.html
```

Or just rename `api.html` to `index.html` and put it in the `api` folder, but I must be missing something as a I don't understand your `.*quea/api.html` path...

Comment: I'm feeling like this should work, but I'm getting a 500 Internal Server Error, which means something's not right with my `.htaccess`.

Comment: You can't have any `Alias` in a `.htaccess` file, hence the 500. See the contexts in https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html